# What is a numeric value of PlotStyle?

Tags: plotting, style

In the documentation of `Plot`, under Options / PlotTheme, there is this example:

```
Plot[{Sin[x], Cos[x]}, {x, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotTheme -> "Business", PlotStyle -> 96]
```

I can't find in the documentation what `PlotStyle -> Number` means. Trial and error indicates this number can be in (0,116), which strikes me as a strange upper bound. The effect seems to be an alteration of the color.

What is the meaning of `PlotStyle -> Number`?

Comment: The number may be an index for `ColorData`, `Table[{n, ColorData[n] /@ Range[5]}, {n, 110, 116}]` shows that the `ColorData`  index can go up to `115`. `116` may be handled as a special case.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The syntax `PlotStyle -> n` is an abbreviation for using the [indexed color scheme](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ColorData.html): `PlotStyle -> ColorData[Number]`.

There are 114 color schemes available in my version.

```
$Version
(* "12.3.1 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (June 24, 2021)" *)

Max@ColorData["Indexed"]
(* 114 *)
```

You can make a table of all the colors.

```
Grid[{#, ColorData[#, "Image"]} & /@ ColorData["Indexed"]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]